# Ansible: Do not register skipped iterations

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have nested when condition? The issue I am facing is when getting the return codes from the register. The issue is for skipped tasks. There is no return code. Is there a way not to include skipped tasks in register outputResults.results. Somehow, I need to get the return code to process the next task. Below is my code snippet

```yaml
- command: "perform some comand which can be success or fail"
  loop: "{{ listOfWarFiles }}"
  when: item.needToDeploy | bool == true
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: outputResults
```

Answer (score 2):

All results will be registered. It's not possible to selectively register results in the loop. There are more options on how to solve the problem.

1. It is possible to [reject](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.rejectattr) failed tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results|
                rejectattr('rc', 'eq', 1)|
                list }}"
```

2. It is possible to [select](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) succesfull tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results|
                selectattr('rc', 'eq', 0)|
                list }}"
```

3. The previous options will fail if the attribute *rc* is missing in the results. Best option is to use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) which will silently ommit missing *rc* attributes

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results|
                json_query('[?rc == `0`]') }}"
```

---

Example 1.

In the playbook below the command randomly returns true or fail. The first debug shows all results. The second debug shows only items which succeeded

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    listOfWarFiles:
      - {file: file1.war, needToDeploy: true}
      - {file: file2.war, needToDeploy: true}
      - {file: file3.war, needToDeploy: true}
  tasks:
    - name: "perform some comand which can be success or fail"
      command: bash -c '(( RANDOM%10 > 5 ))'
      loop: "{{ listOfWarFiles }}"
      when: item.needToDeploy|bool
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: outputResults
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item.item.file }} rc: {{ item.rc }}"
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item.item.file }} rc: {{ item.rc }}"
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results|
                rejectattr('rc', 'eq', 1)|
                list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
  msg: 'item: file1.war rc: 1'
  msg: 'item: file2.war rc: 1'
  msg: 'item: file3.war rc: 0'

TASK [debug] ****
  msg: 'item: file3.war rc: 0'
```

---

Example 2.

A disabled item `needToDeploy: false` will be skipped in the loop. In this case, the attribute *rc* will be missing in the result. To avoid error `'dict object' has no attribute rc`, set `default('skipped')` value and use *json_query*. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    listOfWarFiles:
      - {file: file1.war, needToDeploy: true}
      - {file: file2.war, needToDeploy: false}
      - {file: file3.war, needToDeploy: true}
  tasks:
    - name: "perform some comand which can be success or fail"
      command: bash -c '(( RANDOM%10 > 5 ))'
      loop: "{{ listOfWarFiles }}"
      when: item.needToDeploy|bool
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: outputResults
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item.item.file }} rc: {{ item.rc|default('skipped') }}"
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "item: {{ item.item.file }} rc: {{ item.rc }}"
      loop: "{{ outputResults.results|json_query('[?rc == `0`]') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
  msg: 'item: file1.war rc: 0'
  msg: 'item: file2.war rc: skipped'
  msg: 'item: file3.war rc: 1'

TASK [debug] ****
  msg: 'item: file1.war rc: 0'
```

Comment: hi my concern is skipped. For instance, if skipped usually will not have return code. Return code is crucial because if 0 i will do some task if 1 will perform another task. However, skipped no return code and it should be as expected as skipped should npt be take. I got come out with below coding but not usre is that correct way. what i did was in next task i added => when: item.changed | default(false) | bool == true and item.rc != 0

Comment: so it will check first whether changed. Usually skipped i observed will be false, for the rest it will be true whether got hit error or not hit error. Can i know is this correct approach? I need to display the fail items as well. only skipped item should not be displayed in register

Comment: The attribute *rc* will be missing in the result only if the item is skipped. The item will be skipped if it is disabled. I've added Example 2. how to handle missing *rc* attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I know if do like this => when: item.changed | default(false) | bool == true and item.rc != 0, will there be any impact?

Comment: This condition doesn't make any sense and will fail if the item is skipped. 1) command without [creates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) will always set "changed: true" 2) "bool == true" is redundant 3) "item.rc" will fail if the item is skipped 4) States of a task "changed" and "failed" are mutually exclusive.